# How to add npm dependency with tilde or caret during npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

I developed an npm module (let's call it `module-x`) that I regularly update and publish on the npm platform.

Software that uses this module installs it by running `npm i module-x` but in dependencies section of the `package.json` the `module-x` is installed with a fixed version (`module-x: "1.0.0"`).

I'd like to use the tilde or caret version instead resulting in something like this `"module-x" : "~1.0.0"`.

I've seen that other libraries like `request` can do this, but how they do it?

Comment: The default for npm is to use semver versioning, so `^1.0.0` should be what your getting.  Check your `.npmrc` make sure you haven't set `save-exact=true` to override this behaviour.

Comment: Hello @Keith, thank you for the reponse. 

I was using 0.0.x and it seems it isn't supported by npm and it must start from 1.0.0 (as described [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) ). Now it's using caret versioning.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix in the `package.json` file (whether `^` or `~` or none) depends on the settings of npm on the machine, **which installs the package**, not on your settings of the project. From your example, you, as the creator of `module-x`, can't enforce the users of your dependency to have it installed either `module-x: "^1.0.0"` or `module-x: "~1.0.0"`. That's their choice how to install it, hence how to update it.

You could:

1. Ask them to manually add a prefix to your dependency
2. Ask them to change the global settings of npm command with `npm config set save-prefix "~"` (this one will result in all their installations having ~ prefix)